# How to print parent of a given node

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree, recursive-datastructures

I created a binary tree and I'm trying to find the parent of any node that I'm passing manually. It works fine on left subtree but gives me none only for some specific nodes on right subtree.

```
# To create a tree from scratch
class tree:
    """To create nodes each time an instance has been
    created"""
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.data = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def parent_search(self, root, child_node):
        if root :
         if root.left.data== child_node:
            return root.data
         if root.right.data== child_node:
            return root.data
         elif root:
            return self.parent_search(root.left, child_node)
            return self.parent_search(root.right, child_node)

root = tree(10)
root.left = tree(20)
root.left.left = tree(90)
root.left.right = tree(100)
root.left.left.left = tree(80)
root.right = tree(30)
root.right.left = tree(40)
root.right.right = tree(50)
print(root.parent_search(root,80))
```

If I give `root.parent_search(root,80)` I get 90 as the parent of 80. But, if I search suppose 40 on the right it gives me `NoneType` error.

```
return self.parent_search(root.left, child_node)
  File "/home/vaibhav/Desktop/Data_Structures/python_play_area.py", line 14, in parent_search
    if root.right.data== child_node:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

**Observation**

I dont see any issue the with the right child of the subtree because I can see `root.left.right` getting passed successfully when we call it's parent or child.

Comment: Your recursion needs to handle the case where root.left or root.right is None. Also your statements after the `elif root:` will not work as there are two returns. The second return statement will never be executed.

Comment: where should i add root.left or root.right is None exactly and why two returns would not work. Please explain

Comment: Once a method returns, it is no longer executing, so a second return statement will never be executed. I post an answer, because comments are so hard to format.

Answer (score 2):

I understand why you used two `return`s, you need to return something from the function, and you need to call this for both left and right array. Just use an `or` for that. Because, `something or None` always returns `something`

```
def parent_search(self, root, child_node):
    if not root: return None
    if root.left and root.left.data==child_node: return root
    if root.right and root.right.data==child_node: return root
    return self.parent_search(root.left, child_node) or self.parent_search(root.right, child_node)
```

Comment: This can be made into a static method by removing the `self` parameter in the method signature and replacing `self` with 'root'  in the last line.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. But for sake of OP, my personal philosophy is not to give perfect answer, but one with least amount of change...

Comment: i made the changes in my code and posted it as answer. Shihab, john  thanks for your contribution i checked further we even don't need if not root condition and made the code worked with minimal changes

Answer (score 0):

I just made a small change to my code by adding if root.left with the condition if root.left==child and it worked. This is the minimal change i did and it worked.

```
# To create a tree from scratch
class tree:
    """To create nodes each time an instance has been
    created"""
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.data = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def parent_search(self, root, child_node):
        if  root :
            if root.left and root.left.data== child_node:
                return root.data
            if root.right and root.right.data== child_node:
                return root.data
            elif root:
                return self.parent_search(root.left, child_node) or self.parent_search(root.right, child_node)


root = tree(10)
root.left = tree(20)
root.left.left = tree(90)
root.left.right = tree(100)
root.left.left.left = tree(80)
root.right = tree(30)
root.right.left = tree(40)
root.right.right = tree(50)
print(root.parent_search(root,50))
```